# Add rulers to a CDockablePane in a MFC Application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, mfc, dockable-windows

How should I add rulers to o CDockablePane? (rulers like [these](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/splitter/ruler.aspx) or [these](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ruler.aspx))

I found two implementations of rulers controlers on the web, but both are made with CView derived classes and, since I need the rulers to be in a dockable pane, I couldn't use neither of them.

I've heard of two "strategies" though: (1) make a special class derived from CDockablePane and then derive the controlers' class from it (very difficult to do in this case) or (2) create a CFrameWnd inside the dockable pane that would contain the controlers, what *seems* easy to do but could unnecessarily add complexity to the project.

What should I do? How should I do it? Is there any other option? Can anyone show me a small example of this (maybe just the important parts)?

What I have already seen:

> [How can I split a CDockablePane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184620/how-can-i-split-a-cdockablepane)
>
> [How can I place a MFC CFormView inside a CDockablePane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276420/how-can-i-place-a-mfc-cformview-inside-a-cdockablepane)
>
> Some other links that I'm not allowed to post here because I'm a new user.
>
> (But CFormView is not CFrameWnd)

PS: Please, tell what I will have problems with, details, MFC peculiarities...

PS2: I don't want links to the BCGsoft's page because I belive they don't give any code, just the executables (which don't have any use for me).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier for you to begin with http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/187/Implementing-Rulers-inside-of-Splitter-Panes

And I had posted an answer that could be useful for you in [How can I split a CDockablePane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184620/how-can-i-split-a-cdockablepane)